# android animation starting new activities or dismissing an Activity

Tags: android, animation

Is there a tutorial or a code example of various kinds of View Animations available in Android. Basically what I am trying to do is say if start a new Activity, I am trying to get that activity start out like zoom in till it fills the screen or Fade out when I am going to finish the activity. Is there a way i can do this ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
-Chandu

Comment: Android Itself provides the Animations on activity change. Goto Settings>Display>Animation>Check All Animations option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to use OverridePendingTransition from the activity: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Some examples with Fade in/out can be found here: http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/splash-fade-activity-animations-overridependingtransition-t9464.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:zAdjustment="top"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="1000" />
```

Zoom:

```
<scale
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
android:fromXScale=".1"
android:fromYScale=".1"
android:toXScale="1.0"
android:toYScale="1.0"
android:duration="2000" />
```